# Docker how to make python 3.8 as default

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, python-3.8

I'm trying to update an existing Dockerfile to switch from `python3.5` to `python3.8`, previously it was creating a symlink for `python3.5` and `pip3` like this:

```
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

I've updated the Dockerfile to install `python3.8` from `deadsnakes:ppa`

```
apt-get install python3-pip python3.8-dev python3.8-distutils python3.8-venv
```

if I remove `python3-pip`, it complains about gcc

> C compiler or Python headers are not installed on this system. Try to run: sudo apt-get install gcc python3-dev

with these installations in place I'm trying to update existing symlink creation something like this:

```
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
```

it fails, saying

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python3': File exists

which I assume fails because `python3` points to `python3.6`.
if I try: `RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python` it doesn't complain about symlink and image gets build successfully, but fails while installing requirements later (we use Makefile targets to install dependencies inside the container using `pip` and `pip-sync`):

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'python-apt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

which I assume because `python-apt` gets installed as part of the default `python3.6` installation and `python3.8` pip can't uninstall it.

PS: my Dockerfile image is based on **Ubunut 18.04** which comes with `python3.6` as default.

How can I properly switch Dockerfile / image from `python3.5` to `python3.8`? so I can later use `pip` directly and it points to `python3.8`'s `pip`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replacing the system python in this way is usually not a good idea (as it can break operating-system-level programs which depend on those executables) -- I go over that a little bit in [this video I made "why not global pip / virtualenv?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O390_abzo08)

A better way is to create a prefix and put that on the `PATH` earlier (this allows system executables to continue to work, but bare `python` / `python3` / etc. will use your other executable)

in the case of deadsnakes which it seems like you're using, something like this should work:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN : \
    && apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python3.8-venv \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && :

RUN python3.8 -m venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH
```

the `ENV` line is the key here, that puts the virtualenv on the beginning of the path

```
$ docker build -t test . 
...
$ docker run --rm -ti test bash -c 'which python && python --version && which pip && pip --version'
/venv/bin/python
Python 3.8.5
/venv/bin/pip
pip 20.1.1 from /venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of deadsnakes

Comment: thank you @Anthony for contribution, initially, I was looking for a solution that didn't involve `virtualenv` but installed `python3.8` wanted to tinker with packages installed at the system level that it didn't like ... long story short incorporating `virtualenv` was the best option available .. again thanks!

Comment: thanks, this works. Can I put everything under one RUN command though?
If I have to install python3-venv, set env, and then run pip install ..., can I chain those under one RUN command? I often see Dockerfiles having one huge RUN command, probably to have small layers. RUN commands can be chained with && sure, but an ENV in the middle is tricky. Maybe I can just have
apt-get install -y python3.8-venv && 
python3.8 -m venv /venv &&
PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH &&
pip install stuff
And then I can have the ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH
again to make it permanent inside docker. What do you think?

Answer (score 6):

Why not just build a new image from ubuntu:18.04 with the desired config you need?
Like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update && apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && install python3.8 -y
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip && \
    ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I'm actually doing all these steps, I've skipped those lines where I'm adding `deadsnakes:ppa` to keep the question short, let me try this

Comment: it builds the image successfully but as I said, there's a step involved later in which we use Makefile targets to install dependencies inside the container using `pip` and `pip-sync` that fails on Cannot uninstall 'python-apt'.

Comment: Please don't do a separate RUN for the `apt update`, this creates a new layer that will be stored in the cache which could lead in some situations to packages not found when you try to install them later.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and enable your python version.

```
# Python 3.8 and pip3
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3.8
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

Comment: when I try this version it asks me to give an input of the geographic area. Is there a way to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, modifying the OS (like getting new Ubuntu clean os) is not favorable, because the current OS is too complicated. For example, my base OS is FROM ufoym/deepo:all-cu101.

So, to modify the existing python (3.6) to python 3.8, I added these 2 lines:

```
RUN apt-get update -qq   && apt-get install -y -qq python3.8

RUN rm /usr/bin/python && rm /usr/bin/python3 && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python &&  ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3 \
    && rm /usr/local/bin/python && rm /usr/local/bin/python3 && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python &&  ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python3 \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev python3.8-dev && python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
```

The first step is to install the python3.8;
The second step is to modify the softlink of python and python3 to point to python3.8
After that, install python3-pip, and update it to make sure the pip is using the current python 3.8 environment.